# Import android.os.CancellationSignal cannot be resolved ORMLite on Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

**EDIT:**

The error was occurring with `ORMLite` version `4.48`.  I rolled back to `4.45` and the error stopped happening.

---

I've implemented a database using `ORMLite` for Android following the directions on the website.  However, any time I try and write to the database, I get an exception:

```
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[com.mypackage.instagram.UpdateInstagramPhotosService]
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.compileStatement(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:146)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doStatements(TableUtils.java:460)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doCreateTable(TableUtils.java:443)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:220)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:53)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.mypackage.database.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:33)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.onCreate(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:209)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:66)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:306)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.mypackage.instagram.UpdateInstagramPhotosService.performUpdate(UpdateInstagramPhotosService.java:85)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.mypackage.PhotoUpdateService.onHandleIntent(PhotoUpdateService.java:27)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.<clinit>(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:33)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    ... 17 more
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057): Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    The import android.os.CancellationSignal cannot be resolved
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    CancellationSignal cannot be resolved to a type
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    CancellationSignal cannot be resolved to a type
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    CancellationSignal cannot be resolved to a type
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    CancellationSignal cannot be resolved to a type
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    CancellationSignal cannot be resolved to a type
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.compat.JellyBeanApiCompatibility.<init>(JellyBeanApiCompatibility.java:5)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.compat.ApiCompatibilityUtils.<clinit>(ApiCompatibilityUtils.java:40)
10-24 15:15:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(12057):    ... 18 more
```

This is happening in an `IntentService` subclass.  Here's some relevant code from that class:

```
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
static {
    OpenHelperManager.setOpenHelperClass(DatabaseHelper.class);
}

public DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
    if (databaseHelper == null) {
        databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
    }
    return databaseHelper;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (databaseHelper != null) {
        OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
        databaseHelper = null;
    }
}
```

I can import `android.os.CancellationSignal` in my code just fine.

Comment: I had the same problem with version 4.48.

Comment: Thanks for the same problem And I swiched to lower version too

Comment: I also encountered such a crash. Just switched to 4.47 and everything is ok now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was happening the same with me, thanks for the help... When rolled back to 4.45, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

> Import android.os.CancellationSignal cannot be resolved ORMLite on Android

This was happening on the trunk version of the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) source.  4.48 added the first start of Android compatibility layer which (unfortunately) means that there are classes there that don't compile under earlier versions of Android API.

That said, I had forgotten to upgrade the pom.xml file for the appropriate version of the Android API.  The 4.48 release made the following change which should work for you ask well.

```
<!-- <android-version>2.3.3</android-version> -->
<android-version>4.1.1.4</android-version>
```